# Inserting symbol in excel with php

Tags: php, excel, com, mathematical-expressions

I'm trying to insert the **≥** sign in **Excel** with the **Com Object** from **PHP**

I've tried using `chr(242)`, **`&#243;`** but I get only characters from ISO-8859-1 charset

I now have no idea what to use to insert the character.

Here is my function :

```
$string = str_replace('>=', chr(242), $string);
```

Comment: What is the excel value for the ≥ sign? You might need to convert to something else.

Comment: Lazy option: Manually create an Excel file, put that character in it, read it out in PHP, get that character sequence as it appears in PHP and use that. Better option: specify the character set of the Excel file (no idea how, sure it must be possible though) and insert the correct code-point from that character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's giving you the idea that 242 in any way resolves to "≥". `chr` simply gives you the byte value for that number, and "≥" is not in ISO-8859 or any other single-byte encoding I know of. For the UTF-8 encoded value, use `"\xE2\x89\xA5"`, or simply `'≥'` if you encode your source code in UTF-8.

Excel notoriously sucks with encodings though, so I don't know that this will actually display correctly in Excel.

Comment: Since my .php file is encoded in **Cp1252** when I paste '≥' it eclipse says the file must be saved in UTF-8. Won't that create bugs?  Btw, `"\xE2\x89\xA5"` didn't work.  Also, if i save as UTF-8, it writes `'â‰¥'`

Comment: Since CP1252 cannot encode "≥" (as I said), yes, you'll have to save it in an encoding that can encode it. I don't know whether that'll lead to bugs, that depends on your code.

Comment: `"\xE2\x89\xA5"` and `'≥'` resulted in the same result : `'â‰¥'`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That means you have inserted the correct bytes (a UTF-8 encoded "≥"), but Excel is too dense to correctly understand it. I don't know what encoding Excel expects or how it can be persuaded to accept anything but CP1252 encoded text (which, again, cannot represent "≥").